# pygame adding images to the player class

Tags: python, pygame

I am having some trouble adding images to my classes. I would like to have my player be a cartoon character but I do not want animations. I just want the player to be a still image. I tried loading a png file and setting the self.image= to the file but that did not work. Thanks for the help!

My code can be found here https://gist.github.com/eddison12345/0c55cc5e0af93854582f1c972b55fc31

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self,X,Y,W,H):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)



    self.image=pygame.image.load("PlayerOne.png")

    self.rect=self.image.get_rect()


    self.X=X
    self.Y=Y
    self.W=W
    self.H=H

    self.rect=pygame.Rect(self.X,self.Y,self.H,self.W)

    self.objectVy=0
    self.RUN_SPEED= 10
    self.JUMP_SPEED=5
    self.GRAVITY=2
    self.GROUND=600
    self.RED=RED




def draw(self,screen):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.RED, self.rect)   

def redrawGameWindow():
screen.fill(BLACK)


player1.draw(screen)                            #DRAWING THE PLAYER
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Just posted the code where the problem is.

Comment: Your posted code seems to be missing the problematic section that loads an image from a file. Can you fix this please?

Comment: Just updated it to show what I tried doing before

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `X`, `Y`, `H` and `W` attributes. You don't need them. The size and position of the sprite is already stored in the `rect` attribute. To alter its position, just call [`move_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip).

Remove your `draw` function. Create a [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), add your `Sprite` to it, and call its [`draw` function](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw). This will blit the Sprite's `image` to the position stored in the Sprite's `rect` attribute.